# Zsh shell: compaudit:148: unknown group

Tags: zsh, group

Whenever I open the zsh shell, it outputs these 3 lines:

```
compaudit:148: unknown group
compaudit:148: unknown group
compaudit:148: unknown group
```

When I run the `compaudit` command, it outputs this line:

```
compaudit:148: unknown group
```

My suspicion is that this has something to do with my corrupted /etc/group file (which caused my admin account to lose sudo privilege, but I have fixed that with recovery mode; however, that corrupted file also caused a lot of group-related error that I'm unable to fix). I used to backup my system on a hard drive, but it has recently failed and I haven't replace it.

Is there anyway to fix this, and if it's because of the corrupted /etc/group file, is there any way to recover it? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You can ran `compaudit` via `strace` and it shows to you more specific info about your problem.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk Thanks, can you tell me the specific command for that?

Comment: I wrote about it. The command name is `strace`. If you don't have it, the install it from repository.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk, `compaudit` is a zsh function, you can't run it under strace (other than by `strace`ing a new zsh instance that runs that function, but that wouldn't be helpful).

Comment: I didn't know that `compaudit` is `ksh` component. I just suppose what could happens and gave advice. It was wrong. Sorry @PyGeek03.

Answer (score 1):

That's an error message that is output by for instance:

```
$ echo *(g:nosuchgroup:)
zsh: unknown group
```

Which attempts to list the files that are group-owned by `nosuchgroup`, here a non-existent group.

The `compaudit` function does do this kind of thing when checking the permissions and ownership of the `$fpath` components.

For instance, for Debian derivatives (like Ubuntu), at one point, it expands the `${^_i_ulwdirs}(Nf:g+ws:^g:staff:,f:o+w:,^u0)` glob.

Debian-based systems normally have  a `staff` group, but if your `/etc/group` is corrupted and doesn't have one, you'd get that error message.

I get the exact same error message if I rename the `staff` group to something else on a Linux Mint 18.3 system (based on Ubuntu 16.04).

If `getent group staff` returns nothing, that confirms the `staff` group is missing and your *restore* didn't work properly.